# Can't decrease/increase brightness on Samsung NP300V3A more than 1 step

Tags: 11.10, laptop, brightness, samsung

I just installed Oneiric on a SAMSUNG NP300V3A (Series 3) laptop. Everything seems to work fine more or less except one thing:

I can't reduce screen brightness more than 10% or so. Fn+F3 (brightness up) sets brightness to 100% and Fn+F2 (brightness down) sets it to about 90% or so. No matter how many more times I press it, it doesn't fall below that. For a video card I have an integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 chipset, but that's probably unrelated to the issue.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I have found a way to fix it! One must edit `/etc/default/grub` and add "acpi_backlight=vendor" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. And then run `update-grub`. The keys work now!

Comment: Once before, I did the fix mentioned above and run the grub-update but nothing happen. more important, the loading splash screen broken! I just found some infos on the samsung-tool PPA. Is this tool working? Now I'm on the Samsung Netbook NP148, using the key combination of Fn+ up-down cursor key for brightness adjustments

Comment: Well, mine is a different laptop so I cannot tell what's the solution for you.

In my case, samsung-tools didn't help to fix the issue concerning the brightness keys. However, they did add fan speed control functionality and I use them.

Your case might be different, but trying it out should be harmless. You can always uninstall it later if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This question was solved by the OP:**

I have found a way to fix it! One must edit `/etc/default/grub` and add **acpi_backlight=vendor** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**.

And then run `update-grub`. The keys work now!